# $\phi$ function in Dual_EC_DRBG

Tags: elliptic-curves, random-number-generator, number-theory, dual-ec-drbg

I am trying to understand the operation of the Dual_EC_DRBG.  I'm reading the formal specification (SP 800-90) and can't seem to find a definition of the $\phi$ function used throughout the definition that I can grasp.  The definition I found is on page 65 of [SP 800-90A](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-90A/SP800-90A.pdf). Just to be clear, I'm referring to the $\phi$ found in [this](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-BwDuQcMgAU0/UjhTTSYeX1I/AAAAAAAAAf4/SoRVTE6Sm0k/s1600/Dual_EC_Diagram.png) diagram.

Can anyone explain what this function does exactly?  Is it a common function in elliptic curves? Something in number theory that's just over my head?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are almost surely aware of it, but in case you weren't and were considering to use Dual_EC_DRBG - don't, it's backdoored by the NSA.

Comment: @nightcracker Thanks.  Fully understanding the back door is actually the reason for my interest in Dual_EC_DRBG.

Comment: Another resource on the backdoor: http://rump2007.cr.yp.to/15-shumow.pdf

Comment: On p. 65: "$\phi(x)$ maps field elements to non-negative integers, taking the bit vector representation of a field element and interpreting it as the binary expansion of an integer." You should explain what's wrong with that explanation.

Comment: Another resource on the backdoor and how to exploit it: http://jiggerwit.wordpress.com/2013/09/25/the-nsa-back-door-to-nist/ (I think this was the most clear article I read on the subject)

Comment: @K.G. So if I understand correctly, in other words $\phi(\chi)$  takes a bit array representing an integer and converts that bit array to a non-negative integer in base 2.  If I am correct that seems like a lot of technical language to say it maps negative integers to their positive congruence class.

Comment: I think they're using 'bit vector' in a way that is specific to computations on elliptic curves.

Comment: The standard has a precise description of how to convert a field element to an integer. The field element can be (essentially) a positive integer or (essentially) a polynomial. In a scientific paper, it would be too much, but in a standard you have to be this precise to get a verifiable implementation.